# Use of FIND command

Tags: command-line, find

I have tried to use FIND command but i couldn't figure out exactly how it works. Can someone help be. I want to know how i could use this command to find where the boot.log file is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to use `find` is:

```
find DIRECTORY EXPRESSION
find /var/log -name boot.log
```

To give you an idea of the vast possibilities of `find` please refer to the man-page

```
man find
```

and scroll through to the EXAMPLES section.

If you have many files on your system and if you start find at the `/` root directory, find can take some time. Therefore my advice is, to limit your search to distinct directories like `/var`. Another drawback is, that find runs with your user priviliges; running `find /home -name something` will mostly print only your files (unless you are `root` user ;-)

Another way to find certain file is to make use of the locate database (if enabled). `locate boot.log`.

`locate` utilizes a local database created by updatedb; it has a couple of advantages and also a couple of drawbacks.

Firstly, updatedb is not installed and enabled by default (for security reasons, because updatedb keeps track of most files on a system, even those with only user permissions). Secondly normally updatedb is run periodically once a day, so you can not find today's files.

But on the bright side, once enabled `locate` is very fast and performs only  lookups in the locate database and and goes easy on i/o system ressources.

Comment: If one has no idea where boot.log is, then the find command you showed is too specific. Better would be 'find / -name boot.log 2>/dev/null' which would search from the root directory and dump all the error messages telling you that permission was denied or just   'su find / -name boot.log'